# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in JSONSerialization

Tags: ios, swift, nsjsonserialization, jsonserializer

I am creating slice of an `array` & putting it into `JSONSerialization`
& compliler fails with `SIGABRT`.

```
    let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    let arraySlice = array[1...3]
    print(String(data: try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arraySlice, options: .prettyPrinted), encoding: .utf8 )!)
```

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

## **How to serialize array slice?**

Comment: use `Array(arraySlice)` in the place of `withJSONObject: arraySlice`

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Yes good idea. please see my comment on below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONSerialization` does not work on `ArraySlice`, you first need to convert it to `Array`:

```
print(String(data: try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: Array(arraySlice), options: .prettyPrinted), encoding: .utf8 )!)
```

Comment: Yes, Its working, **BUT** since `ArraySlice` is mutablecollection hence do you think it's safe cast ?

Comment: I am pointing to Arrayslice of  Keypairs or deep array something like that. hence doubt generated.

Comment: @Ramesh, generally `JSONSerialization` can only handle `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSNumber`, `NSString` and `NSNull`. (The contents of `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` also needs to be of those types.) Other types, which cannot be bridged to those types will cause runtime error. And `ArraySlice` to `Array` works safely and the Swift bridging feature can safely convert it to `NSArray` (when the elements are also bridgeable as in your `array`.)